# Store location information, or use a third party source?

Tags: database, geolocation, geocoding

I'm working on a location-based web app (learning purposes), where users will rate local businesses. I then want users to be able to see local businesses, based on where they live and a given range (i.e., businesses within 10 miles of 123 Street. City St, 12345).

I'm wondering what I should use for location info; some 3rd party source (like Googles geocoding API) or host my own location database? I know of zip-code databases that come with lat/lon of each zip code along with other data, but these databases are often not complete, and definitely not global.

I know that most API's set usage limits, which may be a deciding factor. I suppose what I could do is store all data retrieved from Google into a database of my own, so that I never make the same query twice.

What do you guys suggest? I've tried looking at existing answers on SO, but nothing helped.

**EDIT** To be clear, I need a way to find all businesses that fall within a certain range of a given location. Is there a service that I could use to do this (i.e., return all cities, zips, etc. that fall within range of a given location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the data you retrieve in a local cache is always a good idea. It will reduce lag and keep from taxing whatever API you are using. It can also help keep you under usage limits as you stated. You can always place size limits on that cache and clear it out as it ages if the need arises.

Using an API means that you'll only be pulling data for sites you need information on, versus buying a bunch of data and having to load/host it all yourself (these can tend to get huge). I suggest using and API+caching

Comment: Equally important is that these databases need to be maintained and kept current (especially in the case of reverse IP) which you get for 'free' by leveraging a geo-location service.

Comment: I'm also wondering how sites produce those large select lists of countries and states for people to choose from? My assumption is that they query some database, as opposed to a 3rd party API.